# Macbook Air 11" mid 2013 keyboard backlight doesn't work

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, hardware, battery

I've bought a Macbook Air mid 2013 trough a secondhand website. After test it all I told the man that I'm interested. So I payed.

Once at home, I realize the keyboard backlight doesn't work. I've reseted PRAM and SMC. It's not working.

I've opened the computer to see if could be something wrong just like a wire disconnected but nothing seemed not right.

The computer is no longer covered by Apple guarantee and I wouldn't like to pay for the repair.

Is there any other option to get my computer fixed or something else I could do to make the backlight work?

I have run AHT (Apple Hardware Test) and it tells me there's an issue with my battery, that needs maintenance. The battery only has 160 cycles and it last 8-9 hours from 100% to 0%, so I don't understand.

I run the next command:

```
ls /System/Library/Extensions | grep AppleBacklight
```

and this is the output:

```
AppleBacklight.kext
AppleBacklightExpert.kext
```

When I got home I restored everything from my Time Machine backup, so I don't know if that's the cause.

One more thing: when the macbook is shut down and I press the power button, the boot screen is usually gray color with the Apple logo. In this computer the screen is black with the Apple logo.

Comment: Will the following command output **anything**? If yes, please [edit] question to include the output. `ls /System/Library/Extensions | grep AppleBacklight`

Comment: yes it outputs. I edit.

Comment: These are the Backlight Drivers. They're there I see. So now I suppose you can `ls /System/Library/Extensions/AppleBacklight.kext/` and see if the kext contains something

Comment: The kext contains a Content folder, inside that Content folder there's:  Info.plist, MacOS, _CodeSignature and version.plist.

Comment: That then seems that the software supports the backlight. It might be the hardware problem then. If it is priceless, you can bring the MBP on a check to see if it is a hardware problem

Comment: Could be the backlight is burned out?

Comment: Well I would call that quite improbable as the backlight heats up barely. You could check it for any damage. Sometimes, when an MBP heats up alot, the heat kind of "spreads" across the device, but I think it is still not hot enough

Comment: I'm chatting with an Apple expert.